# How to create a different key-command sets for individual JQuery tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs, switch-statement

How to create different key-command sets for use with different JQuery tabs.

I would like the keyboard keys 1 -> 8 to be able to trigger click events for 8 individual buttons located on $(#tab-1) when $(#tab-1) is selected.

I would also like the same keyboard keys 1 -> 8 to be able to trigger click events for a different set of buttons located on $(#tab-2) when $(#tab-2) is selected.

I am thinking I may need to toggle between several switch case functions based on whichever tab is selected? Am I on the right track here? Any ideas most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a global variable

```
var tab_id = 'tab-1';
```

when click on each tab change global variable

```
$('.tab').click(function(){

   tab_id = $(this).attr('id');

});
```

now when click 1-8 you can select the buttons in each tab like this ....

```
    $('body').keypress(function(e){

         var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
         if(code == 49) {

              $("#"+tab_id+" > #button_1").trigger('click'); 
         }
         else if(code == 50) {

              $("#"+tab_id+" > #button_2").trigger('click'); 
         }
   });
```